# How to set multi-binding on dataGridCell tool-tip?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind two text sources in my tooltop for the datagridcell.
So this is the xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <!--Some other setter properties-->
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TooltipMultiValueConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="{Binding Path=ControlValue, Converter = {StaticResource FloatToString}, ConverterParameter=F2}"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="{Binding Path=StatusText}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

And the appropriate converter in c#:

```
class TooltipMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Concat(values[0], " ", values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But my application crashes every time because of the following error:

```
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'
```

I have no idea what value am I supposed to provide? It works out just fine if I dont use multibinding and provide a single text source as a value...

Comment: If that is your exact code - you forgot to actually set converter for your multibinding. `<MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource ...}>`

Comment: Forgot to copy that, I updated the converter as it is in my code.

Comment: Then you need to look at InnerException of exception you provided - there is more info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `Converter` property of the `MultiBinding` to your `TooltipMultiValueConverter` but you don't need to convert the `ControlValue` property as the `String.Concat` method accept arguments of type `object`:

```
<local:TooltipMultiValueConverter x:Key="TooltipMultiValueConverter" />
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <!--Some other setter properties-->
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TooltipMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="{Binding Path=ControlValue}"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="{Binding Path=StatusText}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: What does this line do <local:TooltipMultiValueConverter x:Key="TooltipMultiValueConverter" /> ? Is it like a refference to the converter?

and how should I go about adjusting it to fit my project?

Comment: Yes, you need to define the converter as a resource. "local" refers to the namespace in which your converter class (TooltipMultiValueConverter) is defined: <Window...xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" ..>. Replace your Style with my exact XAML markup.

Comment: I wasn't referencing it properly, at all actually :D